# Ask question directly redirecting to text field to ask question

Tags: discussion, support

I am sorry, couldn't come up with a better title.

So, what I wanted to ask is, before when I was new to SOF, when I used to click on Ask Question, it used to give a list of all the similar questions, make me check a box asking me to remember the tips to ask questions, and then again click a button Ask question and then redirect me to a page where I could actually ask a question, though it gave suggestions after typing the subject title.

Nowadays, when I click Ask Question, it directly takes me to the place to ask the question, type the thing in subject title, and shows me the possible similarities.

The former was much more helpful actually because we could clearly see a brief explanation of everything unlike the latter, check everything in a much more better way.

Anyways, does this feature still exists or has been eradicated? Or does this feature goes away as a person keeps building a reputation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's only shown for [new users](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user), but I'm glad to hear you found it helpful!

If you like, you can visit it directly here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Also available through the FAQ in the sections

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close

and

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion

Look for the words "How to Ask".

I just remembered it is also linked on the /ask page itself, in the sidebar where it says **asking help »**